# What does this transistor circuit achieve in a power supply design?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, power

S8254A based charge controller, it's a Raspberry Pi UPS Hat from DFRobot.

What is the purpose of this circuit? I believe it is some sort of thing that powers up and closes the MOSFET to apply power once it has charged?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: It is an ideal diode made from mosfet. If EB has higher potential than V(BAT) the PMOS is fully conducting (not the diode only).

Comment: If it helps, there's [an article](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/simple-inexpensive-ideal-diode-mosfet-circuits.817/) on the topic. Unlike the above diagram, they got the gate part of the symbol right, too.

Comment: Thank you.
So it effectively is always "on" and conducts like a diode would for reverse polarity protection.

Is it possible to extend this circuit, so the micro controller that is downstream of this can suicide itself to power down gracefully?
It would need, I assume, then a manual way of reconnect it to boot the microcontroller again. I have a DPST push button. I could use one pole for signalling the microcontroller I want to turn off, and the other pole could be the bootstrap voltage to turn everything back on directly from an off state?

Answer (score 0):

If EB+ is larger than VBAT, it gets to provide all of the current through R32 via TR14.  TR15 is off, and the gate of TR12 is pulled down to GND via R33, making it fully conduct and charge the battery via a very low resistance.  If VBAT reaches EB+, TR15 starts to deliver some of the current through R32 and starts conducting through R33 and consequently turning off TR12 by raising its gate voltage.  For best accuracy, TR14 and TR15 should be matched, and thermally coupled.  Essentially they form a discrete opamp.  Using a well-chosen actual opamp may end up more compact and precise while drawing less power and more money.  Another option is using transistor pairs in a single SOIC: that caters for the matching and the thermal coupling without the overhead of a complete opamp.